# Sprite editor/creator

Tags: html5-canvas, sprite

Any suggestions for a good sprite editor for games.
Im making a simple 2d game using HTML5 canvas, jquery, and MVC3
Im at creating and editng sprites
Can anyone please suggest any good software to edit or crate sprites , sprites with smooth edges and good graphics

Comment: This question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.com because it is not a programming question. It's a question about [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). It is also not a good question for stackexchange in general, because tool recommendations are always subjective. That being said, any raster-based graphic editor can be used to create game sprites. Photoshop, GIMP... I even heard about people who do it for money and are perfectly satisfied with MSPaint.

Comment: Also a word of caution: Becomming a good artist is just as hard as becomming a good programmer. The best tools are no substitute for artistic skill and technique. When you want your game to look good, you should better plan a few months for learning and practise... or get someone to do the graphics for you.

Comment: Many editors are available: If you're doing a personal project, try Gimp for pixel designs and Inkscape for vector designs.  Both of these are good programs and are free to download.  If you're doing commercial projects, try Adobe Create Suite (a trial edition is available for you to see if it fits your needs).  It's an industry standard.  You can create pixel graphics in Photoshop, create vector graphics in Illustrator, compile spritesheets in Fireworks.

Comment: My apologies then, and thank you.